# Response times over time graph not displaying for all samplers in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter. I ran a load test using JMeter. When I try to generate the report `Response times over time`, the graph is not displaying for the complete duration of the test.

When I see my log file, it has time stamp, elapsed time, label, response code, thread name, success, bytes etc.

I have updated the `user.properties` as well with the save services.

Please let me know is there any other settings I need to change in the properties files or any other place in JMeter.

Comment: How many transactions failed and what is the response time? Please post the graph snapshot. Thanks!